# how to display each object in array in rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

```
<%=form_for @question do |f|%>

  <%=f.label :name, "Question:"%>
  <%=f.text_field :name%>

  <%=f.label :answer, "Answer:"%>
  <%=f.text_field :answer%>

  <%=f.label :wrong_answers%>
  <%=f.text_field :wrong_answers, multiple: true%>

  <%=f.label :wrong_answers%>
  <%=f.text_field :wrong_answers, multiple: true%>

  <%=f.label :wrong_answers%>
  <%=f.text_field :wrong_answers, multiple: true%>
<%end%>
```

when I create a question like this,

```
Question.create(
  name: "1+1?",
  answer: "2",
  wrong_answers: ["1", "4", "3"])
```

The edit form displays every wrong_answer text fields as ["1", "4", "3"]. My question is how do I get it to display each number on different text fields.

Comment: Is `wrong_answers` a serialized attribute? How are you storing the array in your `Question` model?

Comment: No, it is not I'm not familiar with serialized attributes Im storing it as text

Comment: I just serialized it. how do I get the texfield to display each one now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @question.wrong_answers.each do |wa| %>
   <%= text_field_tag "question[wrong_answers][]",  wa %>
<% end %>
```

Instead :

```
  <%=f.label :wrong_answers%>
  <%=f.text_field :wrong_answers, multiple: true%>

  <%=f.label :wrong_answers%>
  <%=f.text_field :wrong_answers, multiple: true%>

  <%=f.label :wrong_answers%>
  <%=f.text_field :wrong_answers, multiple: true%>
```

Comment: Nice! it worked, @question.wrong_answers each. However you forgot . between answers and each, as each is a function

Comment: hope it's helpful for you. enjoy